# Do you need to multi thread a caller if the API is already multithreaded? ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

So I have Task methods on an API such as this one, and lots of others which follow a similar format

```
[ResponseType(typeof(MemberMasterItemViewModel))]
[Route("memberMaster/{memberID}")]
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutMemberMaster(int memberID,MemberMastermemberMaster)
    {
        //does a load of stuff here, validation etc, updates DB                 
        return Ok(UpdatedItem);
    }
```

And api methods like that are called by an MVC web app in an action method like this..

```
[HttpGet]
[SetupViewBag]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details()
{
        var account = new MemberMasterView();
        var displaycurrencies = await apiClient.getListAsync<Currency> ApiUrls.CURRENCY, null);
        var paymentMethods = await apiClient.getListAsync<PaymentMethod>   (ApiUrls.PAYMENT_METHOD, null);
        return View(account);
}
```

Now given the API can already process multiple requests as its methods are async, I thought the caller/web app still needs to multi thread on its own end as well, otherwise the main worker thread in the callers IIS Host can still only execute one statement at a time leaving other threads hanging around doing nothing? As the web app threads are nothing to do with the API threads.

apiclient is a wrapper for a HttpWebRequest which uses this

var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

Surely to take advantage of a multithreaded API you need to do that? If I had just used a normal GetResponse then my worker threads would still be hanging around waiting for the API to do its thing?

I have lots of API calls to set various json data so I wanted it to be multithreaded.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing parallelism with asynchrony. Your Web API would still be able to serve multiple requests at the same time (i.e. parallelism) even if your actions were synchronous.

As a matter of fact, making actions asynchronous has absolutely no observable effect as far as the client is concerned (apart from the performance boost).

Similarly, this code is asynchronous, but NOT parallel:

```
var displaycurrencies = await apiClient.getListAsync<Currency>(ApiUrls.CURRENCY, null);
var paymentMethods = await apiClient.getListAsync<PaymentMethod>(ApiUrls.PAYMENT_METHOD, null);
```

It's asynchronous because it doesn't block the executing thread (you're using async I/O), but it's not parallel because you're executing one action at a time.

---

So your goal is to not block the client's main thread (i.e., you want to call the web service asynchronously).

1. The server has absolutely nothing to do with this. The client's asynchrony is in absolutely no way related to the server's parallelism and/or asynchrony
2. All you need to do is use Async I/O, which you're already doing by using `request.GetResponseAsync()`
3. This is not multi-threading. `GetResponseAsync` doesn't create a new thread. For details, see Stephen Cleary's [There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).
4. I would avoid using the term "multi-threading". It's too broad, and people often mean different things when they use it. I would use the terms "asynchronous" / "parallel" as they have a more precise meaning. Creating multiple threads is a way (but not the only way) of achieving these two goals.

Comment: Well it was the performance boost I was after. Even though the web api can serve multiple requests, if the main thread in the caller is not being blocked then that surely is a good thing. I wasn't after parallel processing as the API calls are sometimes dependent on the previous one finishing first. For example I need to create a customer before I create an order. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Luke I'm confused... are you saying that asynchrony in the server, affects the main thread in the caller? If so, it does not.

Comment: The client is fully responsible for its asynchrony/parallelism. I'm not sure of what you're trying to do, or of what your question is.

Comment: Well my question was if the web API is already multi threaded then is it worth making the caller multi threaded or not? I have an action that sends five requests to create various records which seems a lot, so even though the API is multithreaded if the caller is not then the main thread still has to wait on the api calls.

Comment: You mentioned a performance boost when you said this "As a matter of fact, making actions asynchronous has absolutely no observable effect as far as the client is concerned (apart from the performance boost)." That would suggest the answer to my question is yes?

Comment: @Luke That depends. Do you want those 5 requests to be processed in parallel? The code you've shown us sends one request at a time, so there's no multi-threading going on at all.

Comment: Yes Its sending one request at a time, but they are awaiting and therefore not blocking main thread.. doesn't that make it multi threaded?

Comment: And no Im not worried about the client processing them in parallel. I just didnt want the main thread hanging around in the client.

Comment: @Luke AH! Sorry, your goal wasn't clear to me, my bad! I've edited my answer, it should answer your doubts now.

Comment: Async does not make it faster, in fact for a single request it usually is a tiny bit slower due to the overhead costs of setting up the callback. What asyc gives you is a slower drop in performance under load. So if we had a graph of load vs speed a sync request would be like `y=-10x + 5000` and async would be `y=-9.5x + 4900`, a shallower slope but starting at a lower point.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I was quite vague in my statement (and probably misleading), but that's exactly what I meant, thanks for clarifying :)